# How much science/medical detail is too much?

Tags: novel, science-fiction

I am a former Molecular Biologist and also worked for years as an ICU nurse. I personally liked Crichton's style of writing about science/medical mishaps but found his presentation of science/medical facts was appallingly minimal. Most of his scenarios were simply fiction on the same level with Stephen King; scary but not realistic. I am working on the second draft of my novel about the accidental release of a virus during a clinical trial and want to use actual facts but fear being too pedantic. Do most agents/editors/publishers  prefer a simple gloss over or even exaggeration of science? Is it acceptable to engage my readers and educate them on science concepts using a character who actually presents details in the manner of a real scientist?

Answer (score 4):

To a certain extent it will depend on your audience, but I think the answer is not "worry about too much detail" but "worry about making it comprehensible to the lay person."

If your story is dependent on real, critical medical details, then you have to include them and make them realistic. But if the story is also dependent on high-level medical jargon which people who aren't trained won't understand, then the first thing you have to do is explain it to the rest of us.

Right now I'm reading *The Imitation Game,* the Alan Turing bio by Andrew Hodges. What Turing and Bletchey's boffins did to break the Nazis' coded messages by beating the Engima machines took some of the most brilliant mathematical minds of the 20th century. Hodges stops the biography to spend 10 pages or so slowly, carefuly explaining, with lots of diagrams, how the Enigma machine worked and how the English codebreakers thought about it and unravelled it with their Bombes (derived from the Polish analysts who gave it to them). I'm not very mathematically inclined so I'm only getting about 85% of it, but that's 75% more than I would have grasped on my own.

And in any case, once Hodges lays out how the machines worked and how they were cracked, he moves on to summarizing. "The Nazis added a fourth rotor, meaning what was previously cracked in two hours now took a week." He doesn't have to go through all the jargon again; he just explains the problem.

This is what you should aim for in your medical book. If you have to invent a [cabbagehead character](https://writers.stackexchange.com/search?q=cabbagehead) for your initial explanation, that's fine. Once you've taught your lay audience what the jargon means, then you can have your scientists speaking pretty much in jargon.

If it's very advanced terminology, a glossary at the end wouldn't hurt either.

Comment: Too bad you can’t have **sidebars** like in a magazine, or links like in SE answers. Some SF novels have appencices though.

Comment: actually, I am now using Pinterest and embedding my references with the images. I store my research there much the same way as I do using Scribner cork board. I highly recommend Pinterest as a storage location for images used in writing because it can also be shared with the public once the book is published. Here is the account I am using for my novel: https://www.pinterest.com/richardstanzak/viral-chapter-1/

Answer (score 3):

It's not that it's not acceptable, it's that it is orthogonal. What editors care about is compelling stories in the current taste. There is nothing to say that cannot include scientific detail. That is certainly something that there is a modern taste for. As Emily Gilmore once said, "I don't watch television. I'm not interested in forensics."

But in a story, everything exists in story world and exists to support story. Story world in both neater and more chaotic than our world. Wounds heal faster. Psychological trauma that would reduce people in our world to gibbering madness, is brushed off with kiss or a beer in story world. Problems that in our world would be solved by a phone call can bring story world to the brink of chaos. There is truly no such thing as realistic fiction.

That does not mean that story world science can never correspond to our science. Story world needs anchor points in our world so that people can find their bearings and learn the rules. Those touch points can be scientific just as well as anything else. But whatever story world copies from our world still has to obey the overall rules of story world.

Crichton is a good example of anchoring story world science in real world science, as he did in Jurassic Park. There are insects from that era, and even bits of dinosaur, complete with feathers, preserved in amber. But that is just the anchor. From there, story science takes over: neater, simpler, and at the same time more chaotic. Because this is story world, and in story world, story rules apply. Break story rules and you break story world. Break story world and you break story.

Can you write a story world in which story science corresponds 100% to actual science? Maybe. But your story will still have to obey story rules or it will read not like a story but like a painfully awkward textbook.

One of the most important rules of story is that you must not introduce any more background than the reader needs to follow the story, and you must not introduce it any sooner than the reader feels they need it. This means no more science than the story requires, no sooner than it is required -- whether that be real science or story science.

Like most other story rules, though, this is overridden by the highest rule of story world, which is that anything truly compelling works. The question then becomes, who is it truly compelling for, and how do I find them?

Story is the one thing that is truly compelling for everyone, but careers have been made on being compelling about other things to the right audience at the right time. Though when it comes to science, I think the question becomes, if you can be truly compelling about science, why do you need fiction as a vehicle?

If your aim is to hide the bitter pill of knowledge in a spoonful of fictiony jam, you should know that that pretty much never works. The kid eats the jam and spits out the pill.

Comment: I use Crichton as an example because my story is like a fusion of Jurassic Park and Andromeda Strain except I use REAL science.  Not many realize most of your genome consists of pieces of ancient viruses and scientists are actually able to resurrect these ancient viral particles to study them today. Add this bit of arcane knowledge to the medical side that drug companies have turned to outsourcing most research to companies that bid it out to the cheapest lab and you can see the problem. How can you expect 'experts' to solve the very problem they have created?

Comment: Okay, so, what you have there are the basic ingredients of a science corrupted by corporate greed creates monstrous threat to humanity story. That's great. But you have to realize that that story is not about the science, it is about the courage of the emotionally scarred scientist and the plucky research assistant/potential love interest.The science is just the catalyst and you only need enough catalyst to start the reaction. Too much catalyst will stop the reaction, not make it stronger.

Comment: actually the plucky scientists get caught in their own quarantine and the WHO doesn't trust the US to clean up the mess they created, it brings in a Russian Biohazard cleanup team. Science is the problem as the reader will find when out. The story becomes a dance of High and low  technologies with a third world island as the backdrop. This is the beginning of a series to explain to the public what to expect when a real pandemic occurs, I even have a friend at CERT who agrees, it ain't going to be pretty!

Comment: Let me put this another way. What was Jurassic Park about? Two things, principally. 1. Cool! Dinosaurs! 2. Sam Neil gets comfortable with the idea of having kids with Laura Dern by saving two kids from being eaten by dinosaurs. You have the snarky think man and the stumbling fat man for comic relief, you have the sniveling bureaucrat being eaten because who doesn't like to see that, but in the end the emotional core of the movie is Sam Neil learns to be a daddy. If you want to tell the public what happens when a real pandemic occurs, you should write an expose for The Atlantic.

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/Bottom-Line-Laymans-Guide-Medicine/dp/0875864554 sadly i tried that, academic doesn't sell well. I'm also trying to submit to Cracked which is fun, but this novel is WAY more detailed. I like the idea like in Ghostbusters, Who do you call when you have ghosts? Call Ghostbusters! But damn they simply botch the job and create more ghosts. The same concept occurs in Beetlejuice. Your experts are worst than the disease. So tell it as fun fiction and maybe a few useful concepts will stick in the readers mind.

Comment: @RichardStanzak If the answer to "what happens when a real pandemic occurs" is "a whole lot of people are going to die painfully before the disease burns itself out and/or is cured by smart people getting lucky," well, the public knows that. It's depressing. Not a lot of people want to be reminded that a real pandemic would wipe out half the planet, particularly since there's not much we can do to stop it. So if you don't have an exciting, uplifting, beat-the-odds plot, no one will read your novel either. Give us hope or stick to nonfiction.

Comment: Steinbeck and Dickens both wrote out of deep sense of outrage at social injustice, and both had a significant impact on public opinion and therefore on reform. But only because their stories are first and foremost highly compelling stories -- so compelling that they still compel readers today, long after the specific injustices they protested have been addressed. They worked because they made us weep for the Joad family and for little Nell. It has to work as story first or it won't work at all. Again, hiding the bitter pill in a spoonful of jam just does not work.

Comment: oh you are so wrong on that, thi sis my area of expertise and i hope with the help of my CDC Emergency Response Team friend to show you there are actually plans to deal with this. BTW even the Spanish Flu or Black Death didn't kill half the world, http://www.upmchealthsecurity.org/our-work/events/2001_dark-winter/ is a scenario, sadly every time it was run it resulted in our National Guard firing on our own citizens. So, is this what we are to expect? I guess you may have to read my novel to get the answer

Comment: @LaurenIpsum I'm nor sure it has to give us hope. It can give us pathos too as do Dickens and Stienbeck. Though hope is a easier trick to pull off.

Comment: some times science isn't the answer, some times it is people and their personal sacrifices for those they love

Comment: @RichardStanzak, so, your story is that the big bad wolf can't actually blow the house down? (Which, as a point of real world science, as opposed to story science, he can't.) Well, that is really not going to work as a novel.

Comment: *You* may find Dickens and Steinbeck compelling. I found *Grapes of Wrath* excruciating and only read it for school, and I have zero interest in any Dickens beyond *Christmas Carol.* I'm not saying they shouldn't have been written (*The Jungle* is also a powerful social work), but that, facile as my desire may be, I want my entertainment to leave me with hope, not more misery.

Comment: @RichardStanzak You have a plan which doesn't end in an extinction-level event? Splendid. That's hope. I might read that.

Comment: @LaurenIpsum the point is, lots of people find Steinbeck and Dickens compelling. Lots of people find Harry Potter tedious and derivative. You don't have to please everyone. Capture 5% of the reading public and you will be a millionair. You can do that with hope. You can do that with pathos. You just can't do it without story.

Comment: i worked for years doing codes on people, DAMN sad and generally futile, yet Hollywood loves to do movies on them. Why? well they are intense and occasionally they are worth the effort. My point of using real science is to show there is real hope. But, hope only helps if people are also willing to sacrifice to achieve it. I loved the multicultural aspect of science, so if one culture can't fix the problem why give up? What is wrong with the solution that Martin Brody proposed in Jaws. "We are going to need a bigger boat!"

Comment: What is wrong with getting a bigger boat? Because then it becomes the story of wicked corporate interests slaughtering poor defenceless sharks. Logically, getting a bigger boat make perfect sense. Emotionally it doesn't work. Give Martin Brody a  steel ship with a harpoon gun and the only way you get a movie is if Richard Dreyfuss gets between the shark and the harpoon gun in a rubber dingy armed with a penknife, a ball of twine, and copy of Born Free. Story rule number one: the baddy is always bigger.

Comment: no bigger baddy than a virus that kills our children regardless of race or creed. but, I thank you for your answers, I'll keep science in where it applies for the understanding of the plot. I have an agent reviewing it now and I wanted to optimize my chances of not being rejected AGAIN. Let me know if you ever wish to take a gander at my story. Here is a link I use as a hook: https://spark.adobe.com/page/wRjql/

Comment: "You just can't do it without story." This I agree with.

Comment: Story is the main thing, I'll agree. But science is not only something that supports the story. Contacting the science, a fun way of learning about it "hands on" may be (part of) the story. Space flight was part of the story of Heinlein's "The Rolling Stones" (or "Have Space Suit, Will Travel"? read them long ago), It is much of the story in Andy Weir's "The Martian". The discussion about how science is made and its meaning is a good part of Stanislaw Lem's "Solaris".

Comment: Great answer. Maybe a simpler way to look at it would be to take each fact, etc. and say, what does this add to the story? Does it give reasons for emotional responses by the characters or the reader? Does it help us understand the "thing" enough to identify with it/care about it? I like the show, Bones. It has a lot of supposed science in it (I have no idea how accurate most of it is), but what's really great are the characters and their interactions. The science is more set and setting. It serves the plot, not the other way around.

Answer (score 2):

I think a better example of "what the people want" would be Tom Clancy. His research, whether it be military, medical, or engineering is meticulous, and its presentation is thorough. He's not afraid to spend thousands of words on intro explanation. But he's Tom Clancy.

My suggestion is to start with too much detail and use beta readers to help edit out the superfluous or simply too technical.

Check out a season of *ER* or *House*. They use a lot of jargon. The audience is either medical professionals who get it or lay fans who do their best to keep up. These writers won Emmys year after year.

And what about Melville's *Moby Dick*? At least a 100 pages of sailing, ship building, and whaling industry jargon included in what is still considered a classic. Technical can work; it just has to be done well.

Minimize the use of drug names. Unless you're saying something bad about the drug, use brand names—with certain exceptions: lithium, digoxin, maybe a few others.

Good writing!

Comment: thanks, I have to admit Big Bang Theory does a great job with their presentation of scientists. We argue over trivia that no one else knows or cares about and more than one scientist wears a Green Lantern or Flash Tee-shirt

Comment: I've nevr read any Tom Clancy and for whatever reason I never saw any movies based on his works. I read a bit of Hunt for Red October and have to admit I agree with this satirical post about his style: http://uncyclopedia.wikia.com/wiki/HowTo:Write_Like_Tom_Clancy

Comment: Clancy may be action packed and full of details but are they realistic? But, forget any book you've ever read on an outbreak, they are all wrong, even Crichton. The problem isn't 'slate wiper' it is SYSTEMS OVERLOAD. Medical facilities have no surge capacity. That's the real drama. Even a bad wreck or fire is hard to handle with current staffing, Imagine how bad it will be on a national level. You don't have to imagine hard: the government did it for you already:https://www.reddit.com/r/thedivision/comments/45l2ol/the_story_behind_the_division_operation_dark/, i'll give Clancy his due

Comment: @RichardStanzak _ I haven't watched it, but that's what the ads for Code Black said the whole show was about.

Comment: To be fair, I thought *Moby Dick* was stultifyingly boring, not the least *because* of all the sailing/whaling/etc. jargon. But I loved *House*. Jargon isn't a dealbreaker. Lack of story is.